# Como verificar clausula WHERE com apostrofo numa operação DELETE?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Preciso deletar um registro, porém, na clausula WHERE um dos dados possui apostrofo. Como posso verificar essa informação, pois é óbvio que dará erro.

```
DELETE FROM IES WHERE IDENTIFICACAO ='456' AND ESTADO='SP' AND MUNICIPIO='SAO PAULO' 
AND NOME_IES='UNISANT'ANNA' AND CURSO='PEDAGOGIA' AND TURNO='Noite' AND 
MODALIDADE='Presencial' AND TELEFONE1='1121758000' AND ATENDENTE='2' AND STATUS=0;
```

Lembrando que tentei usando aspas e mesmo assim não foi.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Pergunta: e a chave primária da tabela? Com ela você simplesmente exclui o registro pelo Identificador, não todas as colunas da tabela.

Comment: Quando você deleta vc deleta o registro inteiro não importa que filtro você usou para escolher quais registros serão deletados. Usar a PK é uma boa idéia quando vc quer filtrar registros de forma eficiente. Se você tem uma lista de PK pode usa-la assim: where tabela.colunaPk in (valorPK1,valorPK2,...,valorPKn). Só +1 coisa. Você não precisa colocar valores numéricos entre aspas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você usar dois apóstrofos (`''`) deve resolver. Mas acredito que você realmente deveria estar [parametrizando sua query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), e esse caractere não seria problema.

Comment: +1 por indicar a utilização de parâmetros

Comment: De fato, problema resolvido. Bem que queria fazer assim, mas o sistema é de terceiros e a codificação já foi feita toda dessa forma, o trabalho vai ser muito grande pra mudar, nesse caso, fui obrigado a seguir com a gamb.

Answer (score 0):

tenta com contra barra antes do apostrofo `\'`

faz um tipo de filtro na variavel que contem o apostrofo e se tiver insere uma contra barra antes, ou verifica se possui uma função que escapa caracteres, tipo [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) do php